# Create a custom file input

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a custom file input with the following HTML:

```
<div class="file">
  <a>browse<input type="file" name="annex"/></a>                 
  <span class="path">path</span>
</div>
<div class="help">Only PDF files allowed</div>
```

You can see an online example here: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/qAvDk

PROBLEMS

CSS

- I am not able to vertically align the button (in red) text and the path text (in blue).
  I tried to apply inline-block and the same padding for both but no luck ... How can I solve it?

JQUERY

- I use `var input = $(this);` but if I use `var this = $(this);` it doesn't work. Why?
- Using `$('.path').text(label);` works ... But I would like to get the span after the :file that I am referencing ... I tried `input.next().text(label);` but it does not work.
  Why?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: You have set padding: 8px 0px; in "div.file a" class for vertical align.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it ... I just updated my example: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/qAvDk. The a and span are vertically aligned in Chrome and Safari but not in IE and Firefox. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You have set float: left; in "div.file a" class And also set padding: 8px; "div.file span" its works in firefox

Comment: I think using float made it work ... Can my code be simplified? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS Problem

Not a problem in all browsers, but the anchor and span will align if you remove the `padding` from span, add `vertical-align: middle` to the anchor and remove it's negative bottom margin.

### JS Problems

`this` is not mutable.  It can't be assigned and this actually creates a syntax (I think) error

> Invalid left hand assignment

There are a variety of ways to set `this` when declaring or calling a function, but `var input = $(this)` is a common solution.  I would just stick with that.

As for your selector, you would need to use `input.parent().next()`.  The input is a child of the anchor and has no siblings.

Comment: CSS Problem: I tried your suggestion but I keep having problems in Firefox and IE. It works in Chrome and Safari. Any idea? JS problems solved ...